# list most popular web services stacks

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, wsdl

I would like to collect here all the available web services frameworks. We have a WSDL file and we search for the most popular web service stack and the best "WSDL2OBJECT" emitter.

To name a few: wsdl.exe, gsoap, apache axis ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preferred by far is [apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/), it's clean, pretty extensive and very easy to use and customize (if you ever need to).